# Using Criterion in Haskell

Tags: haskell, benchmarking, haskell-criterion

I am very new to Haskell.

I am trying to use Criterion to get performance data. My Main module is as follows:

```
module Main where
import SingleThreadedBlockChain
import Data.Time.Clock.System (getSystemTime)
import System.IO (readFile)
import System.TimeIt
import System.Environment ( getArgs )
import Criterion.Main

main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    time <- getSystemTime
    content <- readFile (args !! 0)
    defaultMain [
      bench "putStrLn" $ nfIO (putStrLn ("The last block is " ++ show (last (makeBlockChain "" (lines content) 0 (show time)))))
     ]
```

I am trying to use the Criterion documentation + things I've seen on StackOverflow to get this working. I'm getting the following error:

```sh
Error: none of the specified names matches a benchmark
```

I thought I would be benchmarking IO. From the examples I've seen, the names don't always match the benchmarks. Could someone explain how the names should relate to the benchmarks?

Answer (score 3):

Criterion's `defaultMain` does its own cli argument parsing. It uses the first argument to try and match a specific benchmark name to run (in your case you only have `"putStrLn"`). If you want to do your own argument parsing you can change the arguments before passing to `defaultMain` like this:

```
args <- getArgs
withArgs (drop 1 args) $ defaultMain ...
```

This will hide the first argument from `defaultMain` so you can use it as you please.